# Show results for multiple page-types

Tags: php, pages

First of all sorry for my earlier post, it was just too confusing, and I asked 3 questions in 1...

Okay the code below gets be all the pages with the page type

```
page_library_html_content.php
```

now I would like to add to this code and have it show all the pages with page type

```
page_library_css_content.php
```

too. So I will get all the pages with these two page types.

**Code**

```
<?php
$product_pages_args = array(
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'page_library_html_content.php',
    'hierarchical' => '0',
);
$product_pages = get_pages( $product_pages_args );
?>

<?php
foreach ( $product_pages as $product_page ) {
    $author_id =  get_post_field('post_author', $product_page->ID );
    $author_details = get_user_by( 'id', $author_id );
    $author_name = $author_details->first_name . ' ' . $author_details->last_name;  

    echo '<div id="posts" class="flex_100"><div class="posts_bar"></div>';
    echo '<div id="library_title"><a href="' . get_permalink( $product_page->ID ) . '">' . $product_page->post_title  . '</a></div>';
    echo '<div class="library-content">' . get_post_field('post_content', $product_page->ID ) . '</div>';
     echo '<div class="library-author">Tutorial Instructor:  ' . $author_name . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="library-author-av">' . get_avatar( $author_id , 32 ) . '</div></div>';;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'meta_query' instead it is a array of arrays

```
$product_pages_args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
       'key' => '_wp_page_template',
       'value' => array('page_library_html_content.php',page_library_css_content.php') ,
       'compare' => 'IN'
    ), 
    )
)
```

Comment: Okay so my code now is [link](http://jsfiddle.net/aled2305/TB4e2/) but it just seems to show every page? - Thanks

Comment: I forgot to add the 'compare', i updated the code, try it now.

Comment: Okay so is the code correct [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aled2305/TB4e2/1/) because it still shows all of the posts - Thanks

Comment: Can anyone help me? Please

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect  the fact that the meta  values only  use one  key.  And created  an array  of values.  I do not  have  a wp  install to test  but  meta query  is the  right  way  to go.